# How to get firstname and lastname from email provider in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, email, data-extraction

Is there a way how to get/extract names from an email provider when i've got only email.

**Example:**
external email: `Some Name <s.name@example.com>`

> note: i dont know those names "Some Name"

Answer (score 0):

No Way to get that dynamically.

but you can make a form that has the information you want